# How to edit NavItem of Navbar component in Bootstrap Studio?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-studio

Problem: I am using **Stylish Portfolio** template to design a quick website in **Bootstrap Studio**. I am unable to edit the default `NavItem` (Home, About, Services and so on) from the `Navbar` component as shown in image below.

[image: Navigation Bar]

Other components can be easily edited by double clicking on that component. But, the NavBar is hidden by default and shows only when we click on a hamburger icon. So, I am unable to edit the default fields of `NavBar`.

Here is the screenshot of the **Bootstrap Studio** editor.
[image: editor]

**What I have tried**: By converting the component into HTML by `Convert to HTML` option, Bootstrap Studio gives the corresponding raw HTML file to edit and I was able to change the values from there. But, I think there must be a better way to edit the elements directly in Bootstrap studio instead. What am I missing? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to make the `NavBar` visible for editing. But, a way around is to double click on the `NavItem` component and type the text you want for `NavItem` can change the `NavItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Click on "Show Toolbar" then "Open", this will show  the items.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31505593)